# How does Asp.Net Identity 2 User Info get mapped to IdentityServer3 profile claims

Tags: c#, openid-connect, identityserver3, asp.net-identity-2

I've got Asp.Net Identity 2 all set up and running with a custom user store backed by SQL Server via Dapper.  At this point in my dev/testing I'm only concerned with local accounts (but will be adding in external login providers).  I have a custom user that includes the standard properties that Asp.Net Identity wants, and added a few of my own (FirstName, LastName):

```
public class AppUser : IUser<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LockoutEndDate { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

    // Custom User Properties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC web app, I configure the OIDC like so:

```
       app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.Authority"],
            ClientId = "MVC.Web",
            Scope = "openid profile email",
            RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.RedirectUri"],
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });
```

Since I included `profile` as a requested scope, I get:

```
preferred_username: testuser
```

And since I included `email` as a requested scope, I get:

```
email:          user@test.com
email_verified: true
```

I'm not explicitly telling my `AspNetIdentityUserService` how to map the `UserName` property in my `AppUser` to the `preferred_username` claim and I'm not sure how that happens.  *Therefore, I don't understand how to get the `FirstName` property mapped to the `given_name` claim so that it will be returned with the `id_token`.*

**What I've researched:**

So if you look at the [IdentityServer3 AspNetIdentity sample here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/2530a305b74ef3640e70b137734820f29bc7f34e/source/AspNetIdentity/WebHost/AspId/SimpleEntities.cs#L69) I found this `ClaimsIdentityFactory` which looked like it should do the trick:

```
    public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<User, string> manager, User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        var ci = await base.CreateAsync(manager, user, authenticationType);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName))
        {
            ci.AddClaim(new Claim("given_name", user.FirstName));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LastName))
        {
            ci.AddClaim(new Claim("family_name", user.LastName));
        }
        return ci;
    }
```

So I added this in to my app and wired it up in my custom `UserManager`.  And I do hit a breakpoint when the class is instantiated, but I don't hit a breakpoint ever on the `CreateAsync` method and my claims aren't returned.

I also saw this [IdentityServer3 Custom User sample here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/2530a305b74ef3640e70b137734820f29bc7f34e/source/CustomUserService/CustomUserService/LocalRegistrationUserService.cs#L38), and I found this `GetProfileDataAsync` method that looked like it might be the right thing (but it seems like I'm digging deeper than I should be for something seemingly so simple/common):

```
    public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        // issue the claims for the user
        var user = Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Subject == context.Subject.GetSubjectId());
        if (user != null)
        {
            context.IssuedClaims = user.Claims.Where(x => context.RequestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

I had the same problem here, in that a breakpoint in this method was never tripped.  I even went so far as to look at the IdentityServer3 source code, and see that this only gets called if the scope has the `IncludeAllClaimsForUser` flag set.  But I'm using the standard `profile` scope here, so I started to question whether I needed to make my own definition for a profile scope that has the `IncludAllClaimsForUser` flag set, or if there was a way to add that flag to the standard scope.

And to add to all of this...  This only needs to be done when using a local account.  When I implement external login providers, I'll ask for the profile there, and expect to be able to get a first and last name.  So then I wonder what happens once I've already got those claims (or how to determine whether I need to pull them from my user store or not).  Seems like I need to hook in to something that only runs when doing a local login.

And then I started to really question whether I'm going about this the right way since I'm seeing/finding so little info on this (I would have expected this to be a fairly common scenario that others have already implemented, and expected to find docs/samples).  Been trying to resolve this for a day now.  Hopefully someone has a quick answer/pointer!

Comment: Do you have to use IdentityServer3? IdentityServer4 has much cleaner integration IMHO.

Comment: I certainly wanted to go that route, but with all the new things I'm learning with the complete rewrite of my 15 year old application, I didn't want to add .Net Core to that list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (A) correct answer to this question is to override the `GetProfileDataAsync` method in the `AspNetIdentityUserService` class like so:

```
public class AppUserService : AspNetIdentityUserService<AppUser, Guid>
{
    private AppUserManager _userManager;

    public AppUserService(AppUserManager userManager)
        : base(userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext ctx)
    {
        var id = Guid.Empty;
        if (Guid.TryParse(ctx.Subject.GetSubjectId(), out id))
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.PreferredUserName, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.LastName)
                };
                ctx.IssuedClaims = claims;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as I had discovered, this wasn't enough.  Looking at the [source code for IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/e6024ddbb7a6e6bf23e9fbcdffef6da9833c54c1/source/Core/Services/Default/DefaultClaimsProvider.cs#L82), you will find this bit:

```
        if (scopes.IncludesAllClaimsForUserRule(ScopeType.Identity))
        {
            Logger.Info("All claims rule found - emitting all claims for user.");

            var context = new ProfileDataRequestContext(
                subject,
                client,
                Constants.ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderIdentityToken);

            await _users.GetProfileDataAsync(context);

            var claims = FilterProtocolClaims(context.IssuedClaims);
            if (claims != null)
            {
                outputClaims.AddRange(claims);
            }

            return outputClaims;
        }
```

Notice that `GetProfileDataAsync` won't be called unless there is a flag set to include all claims (not sure why they chose to do it this way, but obviously there must be a good reason!).  So I thought that meant that I needed to completely redefine the `profile` scope, but with further digging in the source I found this was not the case.  The `StandardScopes` [has a method that creates the scopes with the always include flag set](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/e6024ddbb7a6e6bf23e9fbcdffef6da9833c54c1/source/Core/Models/StandardScopes.cs#L54).  Instead of setting your scopes doing this:

```
        factory.UseInMemoryScopes(StandardScopes.All);
```

Do this:

```
        factory.UseInMemoryScopes(StandardScopes.AllAlwaysInclude);
```

THEN your `GetProfileDataAsync` will be run and you will get all of your claims!

Note: My first try using `ClaimsIdentityFactory` wasn't ever going to work, as I'm not logging in to Asp.Net Identity, and it makes sense that this wouldn't ever get called unless that is what I was doing.

Note: @Rosdi Kasim's answer is certainly valid if you desire to add claims (app specific claims especially) after you have already received your id_token from Identity Server.

Answer (score 1):

I use `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications` to achieve this, you could connect to ASP.NET Identity database or do anything in there, here is a sample code I use for one of my project:

This is a complete source code from my Startup.cs, but what you really need is just the `SecurityTokenValidated` section ...

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using IdentityServer3.Core;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static string AuthorizationServer => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security.idserver.Authority"];

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;

            var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            jwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SecurityTokenValidator = jwtSecurityTokenHandler,
                Authority = AuthorizationServer,
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security.idserver.clientId"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security.idserver.postLogoutRedirectUri"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security.idserver.redirectUri"],
                ResponseType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security.idserver.responseType"],
                Scope = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["security.idserver.scope"],
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
#if DEBUG
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,   //not recommended in production
#endif
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                        //// we want to keep first name, last name, subject and roles
                        //var givenName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName);
                        //var familyName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName);
                        //var sub = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject);
                        //var roles = id.FindAll(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                        //// create new identity and set name and role claim type
                        var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            id.AuthenticationType,
                            Constants.ClaimTypes.Name,
                            Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                        nid.AddClaims(id.Claims);
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_Token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                        ////nid.AddClaim(givenName);
                        ////nid.AddClaim(familyName);
                        ////nid.AddClaim(sub);
                        ////nid.AddClaims(roles);

                        ////// add some other app specific claim
                        // Connect to you ASP.NET database for example
                        ////nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                        //// keep the id_token for logout
                        //nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            nid,
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });

            //app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this was another method I tried, but I didn't go far with it because of ignorance on two points, 1) Doesn't this mean there is a database hit on every request to get the claims (i.e. Does SecurityTokenValidated run on each request, or is that updated id_token then somehow persisted back in to the cookie and not validated on the next request?) and 2) I need to then do this same process for my Web API, and it felt dirty to do the same thing in two different places (yes, I could write a shared method).  Seemed like IdentityServer is where tokens should be generated.

Comment: Yes, it will be hit each request, this can be mitigated by a simple in-memory cache... I don't agree on your last point 'IdentityServer is where tokens should be generated'. Id Server is should not know anything about application-specific domain, it just authenticates the user.

Comment: Hey now, don't go misquoting me.  =)  I said it SEEMS like IdentityServer is where tokens should be generated.  I would argue that a FirstName and LastName aren't application specific.  However, I can concede that perhaps the application should be adding claims specific to it (like claims that specify permissions).  You see all these code samples and capabilities relating to adding claims to the id_token and it makes (a newbie like) me assume that is what you are supposed to do (e.g. define clients and scopes so the proper claims can be included (client/domain specific ones).

Comment: I just wanted to correct you on one thing.  After looking (again) at the IdentityServer MVC Getting Started docs, I discovered that it explicitly states that doing claims transformation using the SecurityTokenValidated notification in this way results in those claims being stored in the cookie - "The OIDC middleware has a notification that you can use to do claims transformation - the resulting claims will be stored in the cookie:"  I verified this behavior and see that this notification only happens immediately after login, and not on subsequent visits.  Therefore, no database hit.

Comment: No db hit every requests? I will have to re-test to confirm this... but you are most likely correct... last time I did this code was almost 2 years ago. Anyway, cookie size is limited, only store what is absolutely necessary in there.

Comment: I'd be fuzzy on the details if I did it 2 years ago too!  I'm certainly not clear on the specifics of the flow...  But if I put a breakpoint in the SecurityTokenValidated code block, it only stops there immediately after login.  Subsequent visits once logged in don't trip the breakpoint.  On top of that, I just add the claims to the existing ones rather than replacing the whole claims identity.  If it was running every request, I would either get an exception because the claim already existed, or I would get an additional set of new claims added on each request (which I'm not).